# Get IP with no internet

Tags: networking, static-ip

I want to connect to my pi via ssh. For this project nothing is connected to the internet, but both the pi and my pc is connected to a switch.

I am trying to connect with the pi via ssh, but the pi isn't getting an ip for me to connect to. Do I have to give the pi a static ip, or is there another way? If I do have to give it a static ip, what happens if I later connect it to another network that uses dynamic ips?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need a static IP. Alternatively you could implement DHCP on your computer, but this is more involved.

You can use DHCP and still allocate a statin IP. This allocates an alias to the ethernet interface.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` contains:-

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
name Ethernet alias LAN card
address 10.1.1.20
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

NOTE I have not tested this without first getting an IP via DHCP

Answer (score 0):

for the short run you can go to your raspi and write: `ifconfig` and you will see the IP you have in your network (your laptop and pi with a switch perform a network, and people in there get an IP, even when no one goes to the internet)

For detailed instructions on how to set the static IP of your PI please let us know what OS are you using.